# Is there any way to include all of the sound effects for my pygame game into my .exe with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have made a relatively simple pygame program with 9 different sound effects (`.wav` format, if this information is important). When converting my `main.py` to an executable file with the [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) module, is there any way I can get the sound effects to be included in the executable, or will I need to find a work-around (such as having the sound effects in the `C:\Program Files` path)?

Here's the contents of my `.spec` file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None

added_files = [('C:\\Users\\joshu\\CursorHunters\\Assets\\Sounds\\*.wav', 'Sounds')]

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='Cursor Hunters',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

As you can see, the sounds are located in `\C:\Users\joshu\CursorHunters\Assets\Sounds`, and my `main.py` is located in `\C:\Users\joshu\CursorHunters`.

Instead of packing the `.wav` files together with the `.exe` file, it returns this error when ran without the `Assets\Sounds` folder in the same directory:
[image: Error message when .exe is ran without the Assets\Sounds folder in the same directory.]

This is how I access my `.wav` files in **`sound_effects.py`** followed by **`main.py`**:

```
import os.path, pygame, sys

pygame.mixer.init()


class SoundEffects(object):


    def __init__(self,
                 EXE_LOCATION: str):
        self.explosion1 = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(EXE_LOCATION, "Assets", "Sounds", "explosion1.wav"))
        self.explosion2 = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(EXE_LOCATION, "Assets", "Sounds", "explosion2.wav"))
        self.explosion3 = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(EXE_LOCATION, "Assets", "Sounds", "explosion3.wav"))
        self.explosion4 = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(EXE_LOCATION, "Assets", "Sounds", "explosion4.wav"))
        self.explosion5 = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(EXE_LOCATION, "Assets", "Sounds", "explosion5.wav"))
        self.explosion_sounds = (self.explosion1,
                                 self.explosion2,
                                 self.explosion3,
                                 self.explosion4,
                                 self.explosion5)
        self.gameover1 = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(EXE_LOCATION, "Assets", "Sounds", "gameover1.wav"))
        self.gameover2 = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(EXE_LOCATION, "Assets", "Sounds", "gameover2.wav"))
        self.gameover3 = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(EXE_LOCATION, "Assets", "Sounds", "gameover3.wav"))
        self.gameover_sounds = (self.gameover1,
                                self.gameover2,
                                self.gameover3)
        self.restart_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(EXE_LOCATION, "Assets", "Sounds", "restart.wav"))
```

**`main.py`:**

```
if getattr(sys, "frozen", False):  # Gets the directory of this script
    EXE_LOCATION = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)

else:
    EXE_LOCATION = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

pygame.init()  # Initialises all the pygame contents
sound_effects = SoundEffects(EXE_LOCATION)  # Sound effects library
```

Comment: in the `.spec` file you need to specify which files should be included in the executable, docs cover this topic and there are answers on this already, then you build the exe from the spec file (it is just easier to do with the spec file but can be done in the command line too), [docs on using spec files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html) and the [relevant section about adding data files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files)

Comment: Yeah, I'm very much aware of these docs and have read them thoroughly but no matter what happens, when I build my `.exe` file from the `.spec` file, the `.exe` file HAS TO BE in the same directory as my assets folder. There's no way for me to include my `.wav` files.

Comment: Well, can you show how your `spec` file looks like then? And how are you accessing the assets within the code?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Sorry, that's definitely something that I should've included originally.

Comment: @Matiiss It's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pyinstaller` documentation states:

> The list of data files is a list of tuples. Each tuple has two values, both of which must be strings:
>
> - The first string specifies the file or files as they are in this system now.
> - The second specifies the name of the folder to contain the files at run-time.

That means that if you do this:

```py
('C:\\Users\\joshu\\CursorHunters\\Assets\\Sounds\\*.wav', 'Sounds')
```

then at runtime those `.wav` files will be located in a relative directory `Sounds`. That means you can access them using

```py
os.path.join(EXE_LOCATION, "Sounds", "explosion1.wav")
```

and in the `main.py` you should provide the path as simply the path to the directory of the main file (first `import os` or use any other method to get the directory name)

```py
sound_effects = SoundEffects(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

---

Also a bit of improvement would be to use loops to load the files:

```py
self.explosion_sounds = []
for i in range(1, 5 + 1):
    sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(EXE_LOCATION, "Assets", "Sounds", f"explosion{i}.wav"))
    self.explosion_sounds.append(sound)
self.explosion_sounds = tuple(self.explosion_sounds)
```

Comment: Yeah about the for loop improvements, by no means was I actually planning on leaving my code this spaghetti-like lmao. I was making the files during development and was just excited to see if the sound effects worked (they did... woo hoo) but yeah thanks for pointing out that I still haven't un-spaghetti'd my code lol.

Comment: My guy, it worked FLAWLESSLY. The only thing about this I changed was I used the Path object from the pathlib module to get the parent of __file__ as __file__ was obviously just the parent folder with main.py on the end. Thank you SO much!

Comment: @TheAngriestCrusader oh, I forgot about that, you could have used `os.path.dirname` tho, edited answer with that, but of course you can use `pathlib` too

Comment: Never looked into it, might have to at some point. Anything to make my code more readable :)